# How to prevent page unloading with modal window

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I want to check if any textareas in a page were changed, and if so, if the user navigates away without submitting, to stop the navigation and promp a modal window (instead of the one from onbeforeunload) to check if the user wants to realy leave the page or stay and submit the data.

So far I've made this:

```
var needToConfirm = false;

$("input,textarea").on("input", function () {
    needToConfirm = true;
});

$("select").change(function () {
    needToConfirm = true;
});
function closeEditorWarning() {

if (needToConfirm) {
        var t = News;
        t.config.modalTitle.html("If you exit this page, your unsaved changes will be lost"), t.config.modalMsg.text("Are you sure you don't want to submit the changes?"), t.config.modalWindow.show(), t.config.modalAcceptBtn.on(click, null)
        return "null";
    }

}

window.onbeforeunload = closeEditorWarning();
```

With this I get the modal popup showing but then the page gets unloaded to the one the user selected right away ignoring the modal window. So how do I prevent the page from being unloaded and make it wait for the user to confirm he wants to leave without submitting the changes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The only way to interrupt page unloading is to return a `String` message in the `onbeforeunload` handler ([like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)).

If what you're asking for what possible then pages could stay open indefinitely despite the user's requests to close them (obviously, not good behavior).

Comment: Then is there some other handler that can be used? Or some other way to prevent/pause the unloading? I used there the onbeforeunloa because it's the only way I know at the moment to do it. But I wanted to replace the window it shows with the one of modal window because that's what's used for other warnings or messages around the site

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. It's just not possible. There is a reason that you don't see the behavior you're describing on any sites. They all use native alerts because that's the only way and that will never change. Sorry.